# Cep ajax republica virtual

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cep

Oi estou tentando preencher o cep automatico usando o site republica virtual, mais não estou conseguindo colocar o codigo para preencher dentro do meu input com ajax.
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

HMTL:

```
      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="cep" name="cep" id="cep" placeholder="Cep" value="" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="rua" name="rua" id="rua" placeholder="Endereço" value="" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="tel" id="numero" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="Número" value="" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="complemento" name="complemento" id="complemento" placeholder="Complemento" value="" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="bairro" name="bairro" placeholder="Bairro" value="" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" id="cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" value="" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="uf" class="stateselect">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Estado</option>
                                <option value="Acre">Acre - AC</option>
                                <option value="Alagoas">Alagoas - AL</option>
                                <option value="Amapá">Amapá - AP</option>
                                <option value="Amazonas">Amazonas - AM</option>
                                <option value="Bahia">Bahia - BA</option>
                                <option value="Ceará">Ceará - CE</option>
                                <option value="Distrito Federal">Distrito Federal - DF</option>
                                <option value="Espiríto Santo">Espiríto Santo - ES</option>
                                <option value="Goias">Goiás - GO</option>
                                <option value="Maranhão">Maranhão - MA</option>
                                <option value="Mato Grosso">Mato Grosso - MT</option>
                                <option value="Mato Grosso do Sul">Mato Grosso do Sul - MS</option>
                                <option value="Minas Gerais">Minas Gerais - MG</option>
                                <option value="Pará">Pará - PA</option>
                                <option value="Paraíba">Paraíba - PB</option>
                                <option value="Paraná">Paraná - PR</option>
                                <option value="Pernambuco">Pernambuco - PE</option>
                                <option value="Piauí">Piauí - PI</option>
                                <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro - RJ</option>
                                <option value="Rio Grande do Norte">Rio Grande do Norte - RN</option>
                                <option value="Rio Grande do Sul">Rio Grande do Sul - RS</option>
                                <option value="Rondônia">Rondônia - RO</option>
                                <option value="Roraima">Roraima - RR</option>
                                <option value="Santa Catarina">Santa Catarina - SC</option>
                                <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo - SP</option>
                                <option value="Sergipe">Sergipe - SE</option>
                                <option value="Tocantins">Tocantins - TO</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Ajax:

```
     function Validate(field, value){

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
}

var urlget = "php/register.php?field="+field+"&value="+value;
var url = "php/register.php";
var params = "field="+field+"&value="+value;

xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 1){
        document.getElementById('campo_' +field+ '').innerHTML = '<font color="green">Verificando...</font>';   
    }

    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
        var resposta = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById('campo_'+ field + '').innerHTML = resposta;
    }
};

xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

PHP

```
           <?php   
/* 
 *  Função de busca de Endereço pelo CEP 
 *  -   Desenvolvido Felipe Olivaes para ajaxbox.com.br 
 *  -   Utilizando WebService de CEP da republicavirtual.com.br 
 */  
function busca_cep($cep){  
    $resultado = @file_get_contents('http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep='.urlencode($cep).'&formato=query_string');  
    if(!$resultado){  
        $resultado = "&resultado=0&resultado_txt=erro+ao+buscar+cep";  
    }  
    parse_str($resultado, $retorno);   
    return $retorno;  
}  


/* 
 * Exemplo de utilização  
 */  

//Vamos buscar o CEP 90020022  
$resultado_busca = busca_cep('90020022');  

echo "<pre> Array Retornada: 
 ".print_r($resultado_busca, true)."</pre>";  

switch($resultado_busca['resultado']){  
    case '2':  
        $texto = " 
    Cidade com logradouro único 
    <b>Cidade: </b> ".$resultado_busca['cidade']." 
    <b>UF: </b> ".$resultado_busca['uf']." 
        ";    
    break;  

    case '1':  
        $texto = " 
    Cidade com logradouro completo 
    <b>Tipo de Logradouro: </b> ".$resultado_busca['tipo_logradouro']." 
    <b>Logradouro: </b> ".$resultado_busca['logradouro']." 
    <b>Bairro: </b> ".$resultado_busca['bairro']." 
    <b>Cidade: </b> ".$resultado_busca['cidade']." 
    <b>UF: </b> ".$resultado_busca['uf']." 
        ";  
    break;  

    default:  
        $texto = "Fala ao buscar cep: ".$resultado_busca['resultado'];  
    break;  
}  

echo $texto;  
?>
```

Comment: Não testei seu código, mas aparentemente voce está fazendo POST e deveria Usar GET

Comment: Onde seria isso?